# Java 8: How to create java.util.stream.Stream<Character> based on java.io.Reader

Tags: java, mapreduce, java-8, inputstream

Reading the Java 8 docs it seems that it's intended java.util.stream.Stream could ultimately be backed by an I/O java.io.InputStream.

So, I wanted to read in a character stream and feed it into a map-reduce pipeline using the new features. I couldn't find any utility methods to do this, so I had to roll my own:

```
public static Stream<Character> charStream(Reader r) {
    Iterator<Character> iter = new Iterator<Character>() {
        Character nextChar = null;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (nextChar != null) {
                return true;
            } else {
                try {
                    int readChar = r.read();
                    if(readChar == -1) { 
                        return false;
                    }
                    nextChar = Character.valueOf((char) readChar);
                    return true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Character next() {
            if (nextChar != null || hasNext()) {
                Character theChar = nextChar;
                nextChar = null;
                return theChar;
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
        }
    };
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
            iter, Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL), false);
}
```

Are there utility methods which could accomplish the same or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that in cases like these, it's easier to implement `Spliterator` rather than `Iterator`:

```
public static IntStream charStream(Reader r) {
    Spliterator.OfInt split = new Spliterators.AbstractIntSpliterator(Long.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED) {
        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(IntConsumer action) {
            try {
                int c = r.read();
                if (c == -1) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    action.accept(c);
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
            }
        }
    };

    return StreamSupport.intStream(split, false);
}
```

It's better to implement an `IntStream` to avoid boxing.  You can always turn the `IntStream` into a `Stream<Character>` with `.mapToObj(i->(char) i)`

Comment: You could catch and rethrow much earlier (right after the read)

Comment: If you implement it manually ([which isn’t necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28558632/2711488)), it is strongly recommended to override `forEachRemaining` and implement it with a buffered read rather than reading single `char`s.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `IntStream` representing the characters using

```
new BufferedReader(r).lines().flatMapToInt(CharSequence::chars)
```

If it really has to be a (boxing) `Stream<Character>` you can use `mapToObj(c -> (char)c)` on the `IntStream`:

```
public static Stream<Character> chars(Reader r) {
    return new BufferedReader(r).lines().flatMapToInt(CharSequence::chars)
      .mapToObj(c -> (char)c);
}
```

but for most cases

```
public static IntStream chars(Reader r) {
    return new BufferedReader(r).lines().flatMapToInt(CharSequence::chars);
}
```

should be sufficient.

Comment: It works well but makes the assumption that line boundaries are appropriate stream object boundaries -- probably true in most cases but in my case I was dealing with very long lines, and wanted finer granularity.

Comment: @oggotron: I don’t understand what you mean with “boundaries”. The resulting stream is a stream of characters with no additional “boundaries”. If you are talking about lazy reading from the source, you should consider that the `BufferedReader`’s default buffer size, which will apply if you read `char` by `char`, is `8192`…

Comment: Is it not the case that in the above design, the lines() method will read characters until the end of a line, then when it reaches this point it will invoke chars(), and only then feed the line characters in to the resulting IntStream? In my case (admittedly unusual) I have very long lines and I want to start processing the line characters as soon as possible, not waiting for the end of a line.

Comment: @oggotron: You can’t “read characters until the end of a line” as nobody knows how many characters make up a line, until you have read them. Reading single characters is the most inefficient way of reading, therefore, `BufferedReader` will always use a *buffer* (that’s where its name originates) for reading and emit read operations to *fill the entire buffer*. So at the time the first `read()` (a single character) returns, it already has read as many characters as the the buffer can hold and the same applies if you request it to read a line (unless the line is longer than the buffer).

Comment: …and as said, the default buffer size is `8192`. So when you call `read()` or `readLine()`, it will have read *at least* 8192 characters upon return. And configuring smaller buffer sizes won’t make the operation faster. If you really worry about performance, you should implement buffered read and a `Spliterator` working on the buffer…